# uploading image to the web service using WebClient

Tags: c#, web-services, webclient

getting problem in uploading an image to the web service using `web client`, 
my code is--->

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/Test/SaveImage");
            string imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.UploadStringAsync(uri, "Post", imageData);
            web.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(web_UploadStringCompleted);
```

in above code the image converted into the byte array & then to the Base64String to upload.

But at receiving end--->

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SaveImage(string ImageBytes)   <---ImageBytes is Null
        {
                 ///// some code
        }
```

**the ImageBytes parameter getting null**, can anyone figure out the problem ?

Comment: it's a string, shouldn't it be a byte array, or do a 64-bit string conversion, maybe that works. But byte array is my preferred option.

Comment: @marko :: i am already convering it into the Base64String, for whr u r saying ?
at receiving end or somewhr else ???

Comment: What if you did `UploadStringAsync(uri, "Post", "ImageData=" + imageData)`?

Comment: No, I don't know really for sure now.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you ever associate `data` with being the value of `ImageBytes`?

As an alternative, have you tried using `UploadValues`?  The reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144247.aspx).

In your case, it'd be something like:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/Test/SaveImage");
var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
nameValueCollection.Add("ImageBytes", Convert.ToBase64String(data));
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.UploadValuesAsync(uri, "Post", nameValueCollection);
web.OnUploadValuesCompleted += ...
```

Comment: thr is no extension method for UploadValuesAsync,   
i am using it in my wp7 app

Comment: That's pretty key (using wp7), please state that in your question